# Windows Phone Setting Visibity of an Element based on ImageOpened event

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to find a way to set the visibility of a Visual element based on the completion of an loading and display state of Image Element.

Is there a property I can bind to on an Image that will indicate display state?

Note: The app is using MVVM so I would like to avoid code behind if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the code behind by creating a behavior that hooks into the events and sets the visibility. Then you can attach this behavior to your images using xaml.

Comment: Good thinking - I keep forgetting about behaviours... I probably don't use them as often as I should.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the ImageOpened and ImageFailed events and then set the visibility in code behind. 
There is no member of the Image control that will give you the state of the image.

Comment: I should have added that I need to do this without needing code behind as we are using MVVM. Is there no other alternative perhaps using command binding?

Comment: You will need code behind for this. Only very simple apps can get away without any code behind at all (just make sure you don't start doing anything that isn't directly related to the view).